# Requiring file from layer in a NodeJS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to import a config.json file from a lambda layer into a lambda running on NodeJS 8.10. I have found some tutorials online but couldn't make it import the file. As for the [official documention](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html), there's little to no indication on how to proceed.

I have a Lambda called **`LayerTester`** with the following `index.js` file:

```
const a = require('/opt/config/config.json');

exports.handler = event => {

    console.log(a);

    return true;

};
```

I created a new layer named **`config`**. I prepared a `.zip` file with a single file called `config.json`.

[image: er]
I tried zipping the folder and also zipping the file itself.

Then I linked the layer to the lambda:

[image]

I get the following error message:

> ```
> Response:
> {
>   "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/opt/config/config.json'",
>   "errorType": "Error",
>   "stackTrace": [
>     "Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)",
>     "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
>     "require (internal/module.js:11:18)",
>     "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:1:73)",
>     "Module._compile (module.js:652:30)",
>     "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)",
>     "Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
>     "tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
>     "Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)"
>   ]
> }
>
> Request ID:
> "2295bde4-fbaf-4880-89f4-a5b5eeca4a8b"
>
> Function Logs:
> START RequestId: 2295bde4-fbaf-4880-89f4-a5b5eeca4a8b Version: $LATEST
> Unable to import module 'index': Error
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:1:73)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
> END RequestId: 2295bde4-fbaf-4880-89f4-a5b5eeca4a8b
> ```

I tried with different paths without any success. How can I import my config file successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your `config.json` is in the root of your zip file, you should import it as `/opt/config.json`. the layer name is not part of layer's extracted path